# Icons are missing on the ContextMenu in Android

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am designing the context menu in Android. I have set the icon for each of the menu item. However, when I run the app, the icons are missing.

Here is my /res/menu/edit_profile.xml

```
<!-- Profile Image from Gallery -->    
<item android:title="Gallery"
    android:id="@+id/from_gallery"
    android:icon="@drawable/photoalbum"/>

<!-- Profile Image from Gallery -->
<item android:title="Camera"
    android:id="@+id/from_camera"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"/>

<!-- Use Default Image -->
<item android:title="Use Default"
    android:id="@+id/remove_photo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"/>

</menu>
```

I am running the App on Android 2.3.3 ( API Level 10). Any idea, what could be the problem here?

Comment: [Context menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) do not support icons. and look at [android-icon-context-menu](https://code.google.com/p/android-icon-context-menu/)

Comment: Check : http://code.google.com/p/android-icon-context-menu/

Comment: Do you want to create an optionsMenu that will be used with Android 2.3.3 if the user taps on the menu button?

Maybe add a screenshot of your current screen an explain your problems.

Comment: I am trying to create an context menu on ImageView click